# Multiple level (subview) routing at Ionic/AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I trying to enable my back button after accessing

"Scientific Facts -> More Facts -> Insights Type 1"

but the < ion-nav-back-button > stops working after clicking on "Insights Type 1".

My App needs to browser multilevel nav-view, going from "#/tab/home" to "#/tab/facts2/insights1".

I tried to do some changes and discovered that it could work if I change this way:

```
<a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" ui-sref="tabs.facts2">More Facts</a>
```

to

```
<a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" ui-sref="tabs.facts2.insights1">More Facts</a>
```

Unfornattelly I can't access insights1 e insights2 directly because I need to receive a user interaction at tabs.facts2.

My code is also avaliable at codepen accessing this [link](https://codepen.io/brisk/pen/powzrJV).

Please somebody knows how to fix it?

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts', {
      url: "/facts",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2', {
      url: "/facts2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/facts2.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.facts2.insights1', {
      url: "/insights1/",
      views: {
        'insights-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/insights1.html"
        }
      }
    })
  .state('tabs.facts2.insights2', {
      url: "/insights2/",
      views: {
        'insights-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/insights2.html"
        }
      }
    })
  
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      views: {
        'contact-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/contact.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>

<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    
    <title>Tabs Example</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
             
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


    <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

        <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
          <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information" href="#/tab/about">
          <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios-world" ui-sref="tabs.contact">
          <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Home">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/facts">Scientific Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/facts.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Facts">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>Banging your head against a wall uses 150 calories an hour.</p>
          
          <p>
            <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" ui-sref="tabs.facts2">More Facts</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/facts2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      
      <ion-view view-title="Also Factual">
        <ion-content class="padding">
        <div class="button-bar">
          <a class="button" nav-transition="none" ui-sref="tabs.facts2.insights1"> Insights Type 1</a>
          <a class="button" nav-transition="none" ui-sref="tabs.facts2.insights2"> Insights Type 2</a>
        </div>

               <ion-nav-view name="insights-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    
    <script id="templates/insights1.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Insights1">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>HELLO WORLD 1</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    
    <script id="templates/insights2.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Insights2">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p>HELLO WORLD 2</p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>
    

    <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="About">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
          <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
          <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
          <p>
            <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
          </p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p><img src="https://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

    <script id="templates/contact.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view title="Contact">
        <ion-content>
          <div class="list">
            <div class="item">
              @IonicFramework
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              @Cordova
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic flaw is that "insights" are at the top level of the navigation.

While you'd need to nest "insights" into "facts", with nested child-routes (one can notice where the script breaks). While it's difficult to tell more, unless being able to see the [router's](https://angular.io/guide/router) debug output.

Comment: Do you know how to make "insights1" a child of "facts2" or any other workaround?

Comment: @vinoli As stated, "with nested child-routes". Don't make those numbers part of the string to match... as the router knows `:id`. So I'd say `insights` -> `:id` and `:id/facts` . There are several possibilities (usually components and loading children combined). It is tricky, that's why logging is important. It is still the most easy, when the route URL 1:1 represents the nested routing.